# How do I run Rcpp Hello World?

Tags: r, rcpp

OK, so I have created an R package *foo* with function `Rcpp.package.skeleton`. I have also compiled the Hello World C++ file with

```
R CMD SHLIB foo/src/rcpp_hello_world.cpp
```

However, when I call `rcpp_hello_world` I get an error:

```
> source("foo/R/rcpp_hello_world.R")
> rcpp_hello_world()
Error in .Call("rcpp_hello_world", PACKAGE = "foo") : 
  "rcpp_hello_world" not available for .Call() for package "foo"
```

Any clues?

Comment: Have you read and followed the instructions in the vignette ["Writing a package that uses Rcpp"](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf)? Reading that while browsing the sources of an Rcpp-dependent package (RcppExamples is the recommended one) should get you started/all the way there.

Comment: Josh O'Brien: Yes I have, but I would like to be able to call functions and test things during development without installing the package. Do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Package skeleton" implies that you are supposed to follow the *creation* of a (simple, skeleton) package with (optionally) *building* the package (into a tar.gz) as well as *installing* it.

Once *installed* you can *load it* and then you can in fact execute the new function.

Alternatively, you can work on the fly via Rcpp Attributes and/or the inline package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I started off using Rcpp Attributes and the `sourceCpp` function but my C++ code consists of more than one source file, something which I read is not supported by sourceCpp.

Comment: The package load cycle is really not that onerous, and by setting options (see `R CMD INSTALL --help` and `R CMD build --help`) you can make it quicker still. And a package is most likely what you really want here.

Answer (score 1):

To run the "hello world" example, do the following:

1. Start R and install the Rcpp package by:

   > install.packages('Rcpp')
2. Generate Rcpp template, in R:

   > Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackage")
3. Next, create an archive for the package:

   > R CMD build mypackage
4. Exit R. You should see a folder "mypackage" generated. Type the following to check the package:

   > R CMD check mypackage
5. Now, you will see an archive `mypackage_1.0.tar.gz`. Install it:

   > R CMD INSTALL mypackage_1.0.tar.gz
6. Let's run the package in R. Start R and do the following:

   > library('mypackage')
   >
   > rcpp_hello_world() # Try the C++ function generated in the template
   >
   > [[1]]
   >   [1] "foo" "bar"
   >
   > [[2]]
   >   [1] 0 1

Comment: Your username - true spirit of a statistician. I'm totally not surprised to find you answering R questions / being active on CV.

Comment: @EddoHintoso CV?? Did I attach my CV here?

Comment: Cross Validated, my friend, Cross Validated. By the way, nice work on the chess engine - what was the language of implementation? I'm only curious because my friends are planning to build one with Java. The more insight the merrier.

Comment: ... i meant [check should preferably be done on the tar.gz file](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Checking-packages)