# Rcpp: why I can not run the function in my defined package?

Tags: r, rcpp

I use the following steps to achieve my own package:

1)I try to write a very simple function as follows:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int foo() {
return 6;
}
```

2) I use skeleton to make it into a package:

```
Rcpp.package.skeleton("newpackage",example_code=FALSE,cpp_files=c("New.cpp"))
```

3) I run cpp with command:

```
source("~/newpackage/src/New.cpp")
```

4) run compileAttributes to load the package:

```
 compileAttributes(pkgdir="/home/tw72/newpackage",verbose = getOption("verbose"))
```

After this I want to call the function in R:

```
foo <- function( )
{
.Call("foo",PACKAGE="newpackage")
}
```

Then the error is:

```
Error in .Call("foo", PACKAGE = "newpackage") :
```

"foo" not available for .Call() for package "newpackage"

I met the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107431/how-do-i-run-rcpp-hello-world), but I still can not figure out what happens. 
Could you help me? What's wrong with my above steps? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, it looks pretty complete but do try

```
R> Rcpp.package.skeleton("newpackage",
+                        example_code=FALSE,      ## useful but not required
+                        cpp_files=c("New.cpp"),  ## may not be required 
+                        attributes=TRUE)         ## this is important
R>
```

as both `Rcpp modules` and `Rcpp attributes` need to be turned on.

After that, things should work as you do the required `compileAttributes`.

*Edit:* It is even simpler.  Just do do the `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` call I outlined above, that is *with the added `attributes=TRUE`* after which you are done -- install the package and test it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I try but when I use
    foo <- function( )
    {
    .Call("foo",PACKAGE="newpackage")
    }
I met the same problem. But when I changed it in this way:
    foo <- function( )
    {
    .Call("newpackage_foo",PACKAGE="newpackage")
    }
It works.

Comment: What if I have multiple c++ files?

Comment: All variables in R are vectors. List all in `cpp_files`.